# Accessor functions in class c++

Tags: c++, constants, accessor

For example I have an accessor function for a class:

```
class A {
 public:
 int a; 
 int& getA() const; 
}; 

int& A::getA () const {
 return a;  // error: invalid initialization of reference of type 'int&' from expression of type 'const    //                    int'
 }
```

The questions are: 
1.  The data member 'a' is not of type 'const int', so why the error?
2. Also when I change the return type to int it works. why?

Comment: The caller of `getA` can modify it since it returns a reference to `a`, but you also say it is a `const` function, indicating it *won't* change state of the object (which is not correct). If `a` is public, why even have an accessor?

Comment: Use `const int& getA() const; `

Comment: @crashmstr It is just an example, 'a' could very well be private.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong here, but doesn't "int& A::getA() const" imply that the function getA() can't directly modify the data members but doesn't restrict that it cannot be called inside a non-constant function that can modify the data members. Also, I know that const methods of class can't call the non-const methods. Does the other way holds too?

Answer (score 7):

Because you specify that `getA()` is `const`. Returning a non `const` reference to a member variable from a method declared as `const` would allow to modify the value referenced.

If you want a read-only accessor then just declare the accessor as

```
const int& A::getA() const
```

otherwise you must remove constness from the method.

Turning the returned value to an `int` is allowed because you are not returning a reference anymore, but a copy of `a` so there is no way to modify the original member variable.

Mind that you are allowed to have them both available:

```
int& getA() { return a; }
const int& getA() const { return a; }
```

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong here, but doesn't "int& A::getA() const" imply that the function getA() can't directly modify the data members but doesn't restrict that it cannot be called inside a non-constant function that can modify the data members. Also, I know that const methods of class can't call the non-const methods. Does the other way holds too?

Comment: @tinus91 you can implicitly convert non const to const, but not vice versa. So you can call constant method from non-constant one but not vice versa same way.

Answer (score 2):

The error comes from the fact that the member function is marked `const`. You cannot return a non-`const` reference in a `const` method because the calling location can modify the value:

```
a.getA() = 2;
```

When you return an `int` it copies that value and makes the above produce a compilation error.

Answer (score 2):

Let's look into this code:

```
const int *ptr = ...;
int &ref = *ptr; // case 1
int var  = *ptr; // case 2
```

Will  case 1 compile? No, because `ptr` is a pointer to constant `int` and assigning that to non const reference breaks that contract. Will "case 2" compile? Yes, because you "make a copy" ie only reading value from a constant.

Now in your case, method you write is equivalent to this:

```
int& getA() const { return this->a; }
```

You do not have to use `this` explicitly, but it is there anyway. Saying `const` after method basically makes `this` type `const A *` inside that method. Now if you try to assign  (return is similar to assign) `this->a` to `int &`, you get "case 1", if you try to assign to `int` you get "case 2" as above.

Comment: Thanks a lot for explaining what actually takes place, I now understand the mistake.

Answer (score 0):

> The data member 'a' is not of type 'const int'

As far as the `const` member function `getA` is concerned, yes it is.
All non-`mutable` members are `const`ed from the point of view of a `const` member function. 
Therefore, you are trying to bind a `const int` to an `int&`.

> Also when I change the return type to int it works. why?

You can *copy* a `const int` into an `int` just fine.